# I want to save the successful order for another db

Tags: magento1.9.3

Please help me to sort out this.

I want to save all the successfull order details from magento 1.9.3 website to another database.From where i can break the checkout process and 
get all the details>?

Comment: you can change status to complete for all `successfull orders` and you can see those orders by selecting `complete` status in Manage orders in backend..... also there is an option to `export all orders` to csv format, you can export to csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new custom module.
In the event observer capture the even `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` and create a method in the observer and complete your logic in the method.

Hope you know how to create a new module.

**1 ) here is custom config.xml for call observer file**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Namespace_Modulename>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Namespace_Modulename>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <events>            
        <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
            <observers>
                <Namespace_Modulename_Customevent>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Namespace_Modulename_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>customFunction</method>
                </Namespace_Modulename_Customevent>
            </observers>
        </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

**2 ) create observer.php file inside your module/Model directory and paste this code**

```
<?php
class Namespace_Modulename_Model_Observer
{
public function customFunction(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
     //here you can add your custom code

}
}
```

Do not forget active your module before check.To activate your module upload this file(Namespace_Modulename.xml) to your Path(app\etc\modules)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Namespace_Modulename>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Namespace_Modulename>
</modules>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply .I dont have much experience with Magento.It is an bit urgent for me.For module i can google but it will take time

Comment: You can't make urgent Magento code. It has a very steep learning curve and you need a few months of experience before you can do anything urgently

Comment: okay,i will create a new module and test thank you

Comment: I have created the module and  and copied the code to the curresponding folders,bt in admin i cant see the module over there.Activated the module also

Comment: I find out the problem becuase the config tag is not  closed in the above code.Thanks a lot...

Comment: Did my answer help you to complete your task.If yes please accept the answer?

Comment: yes your answer  help me a lot.